# Помогите с запятыми!

Tags: пунктуация

На основе концептуально нового исполнения могут быть изготовлены конструкции затворов различных исполнений практически для всех областей промышленности, на максимальные диаметры и давления.

Знаю, что повторяется слово "исполнений", но сейчас больше интересует запятая...

Answer (score 1):

*На основе концептуально нового исполнения могут быть изготовлены конструкции затворов различных исполнений практически для всех областей промышленности, на максимальные диаметры и давления.*

1. Итак, единственную запятую **рекомендуют убрать** по следующей причине: все слова – разные члены предложения, отвечают на разные вопросы.

Такой подход  **абсолютно неверен**. Главное в пунктуации –  сделать предложение удобным для чтения и понимания, именно это является основной задачей, а вовсе не ориентация на члены предложения и задаваемые к ним вопросы  (детски школьную традицию лучше оставить там, в 2014 году).

2. Это **техническая** литература, целью которой является передача информации, одного взгляда на предложение должно быть достаточно, чтобы понять смысл сказанного.
3. В качестве варианта: *На основе концептуально нового исполнения могут быть изготовлены конструкции затворов различного вида, **в том числе на максимальные диаметры и давления, причем практически для всех областей промышленности**.*

Здесь использованы обособленные обороты, **уточняющие** вид затворов и область их применения.

4. И по поводу **разных членов предложения**. В исходном варианте запятая всё-таки нужна, так как любые второстепенные члены предложения в конкретной ситуации могут стать **сближенными** по значению, то есть однородными, если они **раскрывают одну тему** (в данном случае это подробная информация о затворах).

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, запятой здесь не надо: все слова - разные члены предложения, отвечают на разные вопросы

Comment: Вот и мне тоже кажется, что не надо.

Comment: Так в чем вопрос? Не надо, значит, не ставьте

Comment: Я была не уверена. И не знала, как аргументировать.